# Force chronological calendar month levels in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

If I treat dates in a numerical fashion and always use the ISO standard `YYYY-MM-DD` levels automatically arrange themselves 'properly' in R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
x <- as.factor(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03"))
x
#> [1] 2019-01 2019-02 2019-03
#> Levels: 2019-01 2019-02 2019-03
```

However, transforming to a more human-readable format forces levels to organize alphabetically. Which is to say *not* chronological.

```
y <- as.factor(format(as.Date(paste0(as.character(x), "-01")), "%Y-%b"))
levels(y)
#> [1] "2019-Feb" "2019-Jan" "2019-Mar"
```

I know the easy answer is to manually specify the levels. But how can we get R to do this automatically? My data sets change monthly and I don't want to have to go back into scripts and manually change levels each month. I'm open to easy *lubridate* solutions should they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transform the levels of `x` rather than creating a new factor. For example

```
x <- as.factor(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03"))
levels(x) <- format(as.Date(paste0(levels(x), "-01")), "%Y-%b")
```